# Обработка события

Tags: javascript

Такая проблема:
Строка таблички содержит три столбца:

1. Фото пользователя - ссылка на его страничку
2. Имя пользователя - ссылка на его страницу
3. Текст сообщения. Ссылкой является только сам текст.

На js хочу сделать, чтобы при нажатии на любую область строки осуществлялся переход на страничку сообщения. Для пробы написал:

```
$(".messages").click(function() {
      alert (123);
});
```

`.messages` - класс строк таблицы. Это работает, но когда мы нажимаем на ссылки фото или имени, то тоже выводится 123, а только потом, когда я нажму ок, делается переход по ссылке. А должно переходить туда, куда указывает ссылка без alerta, если же мы просто нажали внутри ячеек строки, то алерт. Как это сделать???

Answer (score 1):

Для этого достаточно дописать запрет всплытия события click для ссылок в ячейках таблицы

```
$(".messages").click(function() { 
   alert (123) 
}).find('a').click(function(e) { // находим ссылки в строке
   e.stopPropagation()  // предотвращаем всплытие события 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".messages").on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('td')) {
        //Если кликнули по td
    }
});
```

Comment: наверно вы имели ввиду `$(e.target).is('td')`

Comment: Первый alert выводит `[object HTMLTableCellElement]`. В условие не заходит. `$(e.target).is('td')` - с таким вариантом не работает даже первый алерт. Вместо td вписывал вот это длинное слово, но всё равно не работает.

    $(".messages").click(function(e) {
       alert (e.target);
      if (e.target.is('td')) { 
          alert ('asd');
      }
    });

Comment: Вот победное решение:

    $(".messages").on('click', function(e) {
   alert (e.target);
  if (e.target == '[object HTMLTableCellElement]' ) { 
      alert ('asd');
  }
 });

Comment: а как будет работать если сделать `$(this).is('td')`

Comment: Не будет работать. Вот финальный вариант. Смотрю, если нажатый элемент не ссылка, то идём на нужную стрничку, иначе перейдётся по ссылке <a>: 

$(".messages").click( function() {
 clickedElement=event.target||event.srcElement; 
 if (clickedElement.tagName != 'A') {
  url = '/messages?user=' +$(this).attr('interlocutor');
  location.replace(url);
 }
 });

Comment: ещё тот костыль

Comment: clickedElement.tagName != 'A    ===== $(e.target).is('td')

Comment: В итоге сделал так:

    $(".messages").click( function() {
  clickedElement=event.target||event.srcElement; 
  if (clickedElement.tagName != 'A') {
   url = '/messages?user=' + $(this).attr('interlocutor');
   location.replace(url);
  }

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".messages").on("click", function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).is("a")) return;

    alert("foo");
});
```